# HQL: Fetch Join Collections from Eager Table

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have four tables:

```
RootNode // Will return multiple root nodes 
SubNode // Will return one sub node per root node
SubNodeChildren1 // Will return multiple for each sub node
SubNodeChildren2 // Will return multiple for each sub node
```

and a similar entity structure:

```
RootNode -> SubNode -> SubNodeChildren1
                    -> SubNodeChildren2
```

I need one query that will return all the `RootNodes` in the table with its `SubNode` and `SubNode` children initialized. The `SubNode` is eagerly fetched, but the `SubNode` children is lazy fetched.

I know how to write a query that will `LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH` the immediate children of a table and initialize them accordingly. However, I have no idea of how to grab the children of a table that is eagerly fetched from the top-level table.

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT rn FROM RootNode AS rn LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH rn.SubNode.SubNodeChildren1
```

but, this always gives me an error that the owner is not part of the SELECT.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here goes Hibernate reference

> The only reason we might need an alias is **if we are recursively join fetching a further collection**

Which implies your query should be re-written as

```
select distinct 
    rn
from
    RootNode rn
left join fetch 
    rn.subNode sn
left join fetch 
    sn.subNodeChildren
```

You can either

disable default subNode fetch=FetchType.EAGER and just retrieve what you really want by using HQL query - It (HQL query) effectively *overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the mapping file for associations and collections* (Hibernate reference documentation). This approach is supported by POJO in Action book.

or enable the collection of SubNodeChildren as fetch=FetchType.EAGER

The following has been extracted from the Hibernate FAQ (The link has been disabled (As far as i know) but i have saved before disappearing)

**In an MVC application, how can we ensure that all proxies and lazy collections will be initialized when the view tries to access them ?**

> One possible approach is to leave the session open (and transaction uncommitted) when forwarding to the view. The session/transaction would be closed/committed after the view is rendered in, for example, a servlet filter (another example would by to use the ModelLifetime.discard() callback in Maverick). One difficulty with this approach is making sure the session/transaction is closed/rolled back if an exception occurs rendering the view.

...

> Another approach is to simply force initialization of all needed objects using Hibernate.initialize(). This is often more straightforward than it sounds.

Comment: +1 I wonder why [nested join fetches](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Joins) are not allowed in JPA.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the query working, I had to do an `INNER JOIN FETCH` instead of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH` on the eager entity:

```
SELECT rn FROM RootNode AS rn INNER JOIN FETCH rn.SubNode AS sn LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH sn.SubNodeChildren1 LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH sn.SubNodeChildren2 ...
```

To be honest, I'm still not exactly sure why it's working with an `INNER JOIN FETCH` vs a `LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH`, but it definitely is working exactly as I need it to.

Comment: Ok (+1) Just for curiosity: Would it be possible you show your code snippet between **sessionFactory.openSession() and session.close()** ??? And your annotated mapping ???

Comment: Wow, this is embarrassing... Your original answer was correct. The code snippet, `LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH rn.SubNode AS sn`, was the one I needed for my entities to work correctly. (All this confusion was due to a problem with my testing environment)